# CMD + W doesn't work anymore (Macbook / Mojave)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave, dotfiles

After installing [the .dotfiles repo](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) on my new Macbook (Mojave) the keyboard combination `CMD + W` to close tabs or windows stopped working.

I found out that when I press `fn + CMD + W` it works. How can I switch back to only using `CMD + W`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing the dotfiles again. Still don't know what caused the problem…